# Surface pressure piano notes: what is that long line?

Tags: piano

[image]

I have questions about these notes I found. Especially the jolly middle. There is a line spanning 1/3 of the page.

All questionable areas have been marked with yellow.

I hope someone can help me understand what it means.

Comment: Due to the sheer breadth and variety of markings you need help with, I think splitting this into one question per highlight is a better option, especially since I think 2 of the highlights are open to interpretation (assuming you've never listened to the original).

Comment: There are several questions here, and they've almost certainly all been answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jolly middle is a [glissando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissando). On the piano it is not possible to do it continuously but you have to move as continously as possible from the starting note to the end note. Note that this end note is noted "8va" hence you have to play it one octave higher than written.

You also have a few "8vb" which are the opposite of "8va": the notes should be played one octave lower than written.

For the crossed notes, I would put my bet on a arppegiated chord, but maybe a real pianist will correct me.

The first sign is already explained by Olli, it is a decrescendo, a decrease in volume.

The two remaining highlighted features are [rests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_(music)).

Comment: Crossed notes - play a clump of low notes with your forearm.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answere your question for the first marking.

It's a dynamic marking. A dynamic marking is supposed to tell the player how loud certain parts or phrases should be played.

In your case it says to start the first bar in sforzando (sfz) and to end it in piano (p). So it would be considered a decrescendo (start loud, end quiet).

You can find the different dynamic markings [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_(music)) on Wikipedia.

> The two basic dynamic indications in music are:
>
> ```
> p or piano, meaning "quiet".
> f or forte, meaning "loud or strong".
> ```
>
> More subtle degrees of loudness or softness are indicated by:
>
> ```
> mp, standing for mezzo-piano, meaning "moderately quiet".
> mf, standing for mezzo-forte, meaning "moderately loud".
> più p, standing for più piano and meaning "more quiet".
> più f, standing for più forte and meaning "more loud".
> ```
>
> Use of up to three consecutive fs or ps is also common:
>
> ```
> pp, standing for pianissimo and meaning "very quiet".
> ff, standing for fortissimo and meaning "very loud".
> ppp ("triple piano"), standing for pianississimo and meaning "very very quiet".
> fff ("triple forte"), standing for fortississimo and meaning "very very loud"
> ```

The list does not contain the sfz, but on the german entry of the wikipedia page is written:

> sfz = sforzando, sforzato => kräftig, betont

kräfitg = powerful

betont = stressed